# Uncaught ReferenceError: div2 is not defined

Tags: javascript, dom-manipulation

Developing an Etch-A-Sketch project using JavaScript - run into an issue which I'm not entirely sure about. Trying to attach an event to div2 however - it doesn't seem to be defined even though I have assigned `const div2 = document.createElement('div')` inside a for loop which creates a 16 x 16 grid:

[image: ![16 * 16 grid created using JS]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYG2y.png)

```
for(let i = 0; i < 16; i++){
    const div =  document.createElement('div');
    div.style.cssText = 'border: 1px solid black; flex: 1';
    container.appendChild(div);

    for (let j = 0; j < 16; j++){
        const div2 = document.createElement('div');
        div2.classList.add('square');
        div.style.display = 'flex';
        div.appendChild(div2);    
    }
}
```

```
div2.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
let randomColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];

if(randomColor === '1'){
    div2.style.changeBackground = 'red';
} else if(randomColor === '2'){
    div2.style.changeBackground = 'blue';
} else if(randomColor === '3'){
    div2.style.changeBackground = 'yellow';
} else if(randomColor === '4'){
    div2.style.changeBackground = 'orange';
} else{
    div2.style.changeBackground = 'green';
}
```

});

I also tried attaching the same event to `square` which is a class grabbed using a querySelector - however that returns null - 'Uncaught TypeError: square.addEventListener is not a function'.
My overall aim is to have the user hover over a square on the grid and have the grid change colour when the cursor goes over it.

Comment: It's only scoped inside the inner `for` loop, not outside

Comment: Ok so I need to declare ```div2``` in the global scope

Comment: No, add the listener inside the loop

Comment: Thank you CP, I got the event to fire